# GLM Binomial, with factor predictor, why model without the intercept

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, logit

In an exercise that asks to estimate the odds ratio the GLM is fitted without the intercept (see code below). It's the first time I see such a configuration and at first sight it seems right but I am unable to find an intuitive justification of why, I just generally feel that this way everything is explained by the levels of the predictor, but if I must explain why this is good and whether it is correct I can not.
Can someone explain
- wether fitting without intercept is correct, in this case and in general with response and regressor both factors
- why
- whether fitting with the intercept would be right or wrong
- if right what would be the differences, in this and similar cases (factors, continuous variables it's clear)

library(MASS)

str(shuttle)
 'data.frame': 256 obs. of  7 variables:
  \$ wind     : Factor w/ 2 levels "head","tail":
  \$ use      : Factor w/ 2 levels "auto","noauto":
# other vars omitted

fit <- glm(use ~ wind-1, family = "binomial", data = shuttle)

coeff <- exp(coef(fit))
oddsRatio <- coeff[1]/coeff[2]
print(oddsRatio)
 windhead
[1] 1.032323

Comment: Surprisingly, there seem to be a great deal of posts about this topic here: please check out the links at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+intercept.

Comment: Thank you, had searched before posting but clearly not very effectively :-)

Comment: There's an art to it.  The search that worked best for me in this case used keywords [no intercept regression glm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+intercept+regression+glm+).  I think I got a little lucky with that.